# Kotlin safe call (?.) implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I could solve it with cumbersome methods so would really appreciate if you don't post a workaround but rather documented solution.

I'm trying to add following code snippet into `onCreateView()` of a Fragment but "thanks" to safe call (or my code design) things got complicated. After`TabLayoutMediator(activity` part Kotlin shows warning to add safe call (`?.`) after `activity` (equivalent to `getActivity` in Java) which could be `null`.

> Original code snippet before trying any solution

```
TabLayoutMediator(activity.findViewById(R.id.tabs), view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager),
                TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback { tab, position ->
                    // Styling each tab here
                    tab.text = mValueHeadlineCategoryList[position]
                }).attach()
```

> 1) Trying to solve by adding `safe call` (failed)

Adding safe call now goes against `TabLayoutMediator` input parameter and I get `type mismatch Required:TabLayout   Found:TabLayout?` warning on `TabLayoutMediator`.

```
TabLayoutMediator(activity?.findViewById(R.id.tabs), view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager),
            TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback { tab, position ->
                tab.text = mValueHeadlineCategoryList[position]
            }).attach()
```

> 2) Trying to solve by null check before `safe call` (failed)

Adding null check, but now Kotlin gives warning on `TabLayoutMediator(activity` part that reads `Smart cast to 'FragmentActivity' is impossible, because 'activity' is a property that has open or custom gette`

```
if (activity != null) {
            TabLayoutMediator(activity.findViewById(R.id.tabs), view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager),
                TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback { tab, position ->
                    tab.text = mValueHeadlineCategoryList[position]
                }).attach()
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple fix : you can do this

```
   activity?.let { instance ->
            TabLayoutMediator(instance.findViewById(R.id.tabs), view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager),
                TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback { tab, position ->
                    tab.text = mValueHeadlineCategoryList[position]
                }).attach()
}
```

Comment: Both answers are just great but this is just to the point as I didn't want `IllegalStateException` to be thrown for now

Answer (score 3):

Replace `activity` [with `requireActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#requireactivity).